# Numpy arange of 2^x

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I recently started using Python and I have no idea how to do this exercise, I know arange works like a=np.arange(start,stop,step), but how do I enter my own variables ?
Here is the exercise i have to do:
Using the arange function, create a Numpy table consisting of 20 consecutive multiples of the number 2

Comment: Could you post your current attempt?

Comment: Yes, try something, anything, to convince me you don't just want an answer you can parrot for your homework ;-)

Comment: Well, i have no idea how to enter my own variables so i just created normal table    a=np.arange(1,21)
print(a)

Comment: multiples of two != exponents of two (2^x)

Comment: multiple of the number two are just even numbers, you want range(0, 40, 2)

Comment: I want to understand how it works rather than just copy it

Comment: @mortis20 range(start, stop, step) gives a range from start to stop (excluded) with the given steps. That's the definition of consecutive even numbers.

Comment: ok, so the result should be (1,2,4,8,16,etc), its 2^x and x its from 0 to 20.  Also sorry for my English, i have to use translator for few words, how do I make it happen using arange ?

Comment: see http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html

Comment: @user3080953 thats exacly what i was looking for, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(0,10,1)
In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [3]: 2**x
Out[3]: array([  1,   2,   4,   8,  16,  32,  64, 128, 256, 512])
```

The last calculation is the equivalent of

```
In [5]: for i in x:
   ...:     print(i, 2**i)
   ...:     
   ...:     
0 1
1 2
2 4
3 8
4 16
....
```